# StreamPlot hangs if streamPoints are outside the range specified

Tags: plotting

Is this a know issue? The following MWE works and gives plot immediately

```
StreamPlot[{3 x - y, 5 x - 3 y}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -5, 5},
 StreamPoints -> {
   {
    {{1, 5}, Red},
    Automatic
    }
   }
 ]
```

Notice the `StreamPoints` has point `(1,5)` and the `y` range is `{y, -5, 5}`. Now, just changing the range to `{y, -4, 4}`, Mathematica hangs

```
StreamPlot[{3 x - y, 5 x - 3 y}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -4, 4},
 StreamPoints -> {
   {
    {{1, 5}, Red},
    Automatic
    }
   }
 ]
```

It seems because the `StreamPoints` has point outside the range.

Is this known issue? Is this a bug?

I tried it on 11.3 and 12 on windows 10, and they both hang.  Does it hang also on earlier versions?

Comment: Not that this helps much, but it also hangs on v12.0 on macOS 10.15.1.